# IE7 web layout problem

Tags: html

My site looks fine in ie9, chrome and fx.
but in ie7 the side bar gets shifted over.
http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/Index.html

does anyone know what might be causing this problem and how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance,
Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists inside your sidebar all have a computed left margin of 30pt, try to set it to

```
#sidebar UL {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 0px;
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none;
    MARGIN-LEFT: 0;
}
```